# Dynamically show/hide columns/rows in display: -ms-grid

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have a class using `display: -ms-grid`, for arguments sake, let's say it's defined as below:

```
.gridDiv {

    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
    -ms-grid-columns: 200px 400px 200px;

}
```

Is there a way to hide one of my columns via either css or js at runtime? I've hidden the elements within, but I'd like to crush down the .gridDiv, so that it only appears to have two columns.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done in your .js file. need to ensure that elements are laid out again if required after this.

```
var gridDiv = this.element.querySelector('.gridDiv');
var columns = '200px 200px';
// TODO -  code to compute columns
gridDiv.style.msGridColumns = columns;
```

Comment: Ah ok, so there isn't an easy way to move say, the contents from column 3 into column 2, without getting a reference to the item inside column 3 and adjusting it's msGridColumn value from 3 to 2?

Comment: yes. `msGridColumn` needs to be adjusted for items in column 3 to 2. Need to iterate over all the items and adjust 3 to 2. adjusting `msGridColumns` will not fix that.